# Jquery UI sortable how modified for table column

Tags: jquery, html-table, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I would use Jquery UI sortable for creative drag and drop column in table. I try this with "axis", but it don't working correctly.
My example:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umRJr/680/)

code:

```
$("table tr").sortable({ axis: "x",  });
```

Comment: Looks like it's working just fine, to me.

Comment: I would this working like a dragtable by Jesse Baird, and I would can use toArray for this option;)

Comment: The above comment makes no sense.

Comment: Ok, I write this again. I would like to jquery ui sortable working like a dragtable by Jesse Baird ;) and I would can use toArray(method from widget). Better ?